# My Database call gets reset everytime i click off of the activity and return to it

Tags: java, android

I have a fitness app that reads a sqlitedatabase and populates some textviews and recycles in the home fragment and it worked perfectly before, but since my old start was slow I have moved the code for the TotalSetsWeek and storeDatainArrays methods to new thread class to improve performance and now it works when I first open the app but when I click away and return it gets rid of everything and makes it empty.

What am i doing wrong with my new threads?

Here is my home Fraagment code:

````
package com.example.polemistesfitness;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint; import android.database.Cursor; import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull; import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment; import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager; import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Handler; import android.os.Looper; import android.view.LayoutInflater; import android.view.View; import android.view.ViewGroup; import android.widget.TextView; import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.Date;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

DatabaseHelper mydb; RecyclerView recyclerView; ArrayList<String> exercise_name, set_weight, set_reps, set_date; ArrayList<String> total_weight, total_reps;  //for the weekly stats

    //making instance of db adapter class DBAdapter dbadapter; SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); String todaydate; String weekAgoDate; int totalMonthlyReps=0; int totalMonthlyWeight=0; int totalMonthSets=0; TextView weighttxt; TextView repstxt; TextView setstxt; TextView fitscoretxt; int fitnessScore;



```

public HomeFragment() {
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.homerecyclerView);

       //resetting in case a new set was added totalMonthlyReps=0; totalMonthlyWeight=0; totalMonthSets=0; fitnessScore=0;



mydb = new DatabaseHelper(getContext()); exercise_name = new ArrayList<>(); set_weight = new ArrayList<>(); set_reps = new ArrayList<>(); set_date= new ArrayList<>(); total_weight= new ArrayList<>(); total_reps= new ArrayList<>();


todaydate = sdf.format(new Date()).toString();
        ///weekAgoDate = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 7L * 24 * 3600 * 1000)).toString();

        //System.out.println("Week Ago Date: "+weekAgoDate);
        //This two methods need to be on different threads storeDatainArrays(); TotalSetsWeek(todaydate);

dbadapter = new DBAdapter(getContext(),exercise_name ,set_weight,set_reps,set_date); recyclerView.setAdapter(dbadapter); recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        //for loop to get total sets and weight for the week and put into textviews for(int i=0;i<total_weight.size();i++) { totalMonthlyWeight += Integer.parseInt(total_weight.get(i)); totalMonthlyReps += Integer.parseInt(total_reps.get(i)); System.out.println("Total sets: " + total_weight.size());
        }
        //Fitness score is total number of sets by 2 in the month

if(totalMonthlyWeight==0){ fitnessScore=0;
        } else{ fitnessScore = ((totalMonthlyReps+totalMonthlyWeight) /(total_weight.size())); fitnessScore = totalMonthlyReps+totalMonthlyWeight;

        }


weighttxt =  view.findViewById(R.id.totalweighttxt); weighttxt.setText(String.valueOf(totalMonthlyWeight)); repstxt = view.findViewById(R.id.totalrepstxt); repstxt.setText(String.valueOf(totalMonthlyReps)); setstxt = view.findViewById(R.id.totalsetstxt); setstxt.setText(String.valueOf(total_weight.size())); fitscoretxt = view.findViewById(R.id.fitscoretxt); fitscoretxt.setText(String.valueOf(fitnessScore));


return view;

    }

    //Storing the data of the past week void TotalSetsWeek(String todaydate) { TotalSetsWeekThread thread2 = new TotalSetsWeekThread(); thread2.start();
    }



//Storing Todays Data void storeDatainArrays(){
        //calling the method in db java class and storing it in cursor Cursor cursor = mydb.readDate(todaydate);    //Im going to change this to read only todays Data if(cursor.getCount() == 0){ Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Start a Workout Today", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //Here we read the columns by their number else{ while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                    //these columindexes might need changing exercise_name.add(cursor.getString(1)); //storing column data in arraylist set_weight.add(cursor.getString(2)); set_reps.add(cursor.getString(3)); set_date.add(cursor.getString(4));

            }
        }*/

StoreDatainArrays thread1 = new StoreDatainArrays(); thread1.start();

    }

class StoreDatainArrays extends Thread {

StoreDatainArrays(){

        }

        @Override public void run(){ Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()); handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    //calling the method in db java class and storing it in cursor Cursor cursor = mydb.readDate(todaydate);    //Im going to change this to read only todays Data if(cursor.getCount() == 0){ Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Start a Workout Today", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    //Here we read the columns by their number else{ while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                            //these columindexes might need changing exercise_name.add(cursor.getString(1)); //storing column data in arraylist set_weight.add(cursor.getString(2)); set_reps.add(cursor.getString(3)); set_date.add(cursor.getString(4));

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }


class TotalSetsWeekThread extends Thread{ TotalSetsWeekThread() {}

        @Override public void run(){ Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()); handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    //calling the method in db java class and storing it in cursor Cursor cursor = mydb.readDate(todaydate);    //Im going to change this to read only todays Data if(cursor.getCount() == 0){

Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Start a Workout Today", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    //Here we read the columns by their number else{ while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                            //these columindexes might need changing System.out.println(cursor.getString(2)); total_weight.add(cursor.getString(2)); total_reps.add(cursor.getString(3));


                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }


    }

}
````

Comment: The blockquote editing messed up the code, please [edit] it and copy in a fresh copy.

Comment: How do i fix this

Comment: [Edit] it, copy in a new copy of your code (directly from your IDE) and put ``` on a line above and below your code.